# Fair or Foul Ruling

Tags: softball

Just looking for confirmation on a fair or foul ruling on a play I made in softball the other day.

Batter hits the ball down the first base line with a lot of spin. The ball bounces once in fair territory. I tried to get it before it went into foul territory with my glove but couldn't. So I am now standing in foul territory and before the ball hits the ground I kick it back into fair territory before it crosses first base.  Since I was standing in foul territory I would have assumed it would have been foul the second it hit my foot but the umpire calls the ball fair.  What is the correct call on this play?

Comment: You were in foul territory, but where was the ball when you kicked it? If it was in fair territory when your foot made contact, then it's fair.

Comment: The ball had crossed over into foul territory when I had kicked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ASA rules](http://www.sfcoedchurchleague.com/asasoftballrb.pdf):

[image: ASA Foul Ball definition]

> Since I was standing in foul territory I would have assumed it would have been foul the second it hit my foot

According to provision A, this seems to be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  So I am not going crazy. I thought it was foul but didn't bother to argue because, well, it's softball.